# remove lex tag block from string

Tags: php, parsing, callback, tags, pyrocms-lex

Hello i have this lex parser template which contains a callback tag which i want to be removed because i get an infinite loop.

I tried with php `preg_replace` but then i get a white screen. The tag that i want to remove is in this format:

```
{{ search:query term="value" .. more attributes .. }}

  // any content between these tags needs to be removed as well, including new lines

{{ /search:query }}
```

And this is my try at preg_replace:

```
$text = preg_replace('@\{\{\ssearch:(.*?)\}\}(.*?)\{\{\s/search:(.*?)\s\}\}@is','',$text);
```

But it doesn't work. Any advice why?

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = preg_replace('\{\{\s+search:query(\s+\S+=".*")+\s*\}\}.*\{\{\s*/search:query\s*\}\}Uims', '', $text);
```

Handles missing and multiple whitespace, one or more `attr="value"` pairs, multi-line and is non-greedy.